# How to sort the result from string_agg()

Tags: sql, postgresql, string-aggregation

I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE tblproducts
(
productid integer,
product character varying(20)
)
```

With the rows:

```
INSERT INTO tblproducts(productid, product) VALUES (1, 'CANDID POWDER 50 GM');
INSERT INTO tblproducts(productid, product) VALUES (2, 'SINAREST P SYP 100 ML');
INSERT INTO tblproducts(productid, product) VALUES (3, 'ESOZ D 20 MG CAP');
INSERT INTO tblproducts(productid, product) VALUES (4, 'HHDERM CREAM 10 GM');
INSERT INTO tblproducts(productid, product) VALUES (5, 'CREAM 15 GM');
INSERT INTO tblproducts(productid, product) VALUES (6, 'KZ LOTION 50 ML');
INSERT INTO tblproducts(productid, product) VALUES (7, 'BUDECORT 200 Rotocap');
```

If I execute `string_agg()` on `tblproducts`:

```
SELECT string_agg(product, ' | ') FROM "tblproducts"
```

It will return the following result:

```
CANDID POWDER 50 GM | ESOZ D 20 MG CAP | HHDERM CREAM 10 GM | CREAM 15 GM | KZ LOTION 50 ML | BUDECORT 200 Rotocap
```

How can I sort the aggregated string, in the order I would get using `ORDER BY product`?

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.2.4.

Answer (score 342, accepted):

With postgres 9.0+ you can write:

```
select string_agg(product,' | ' order by product) from "tblproducts"
```

[Details here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES).

Comment: can you please suggest a solution which will also work when using window functions?

Comment: Thanks for the link. Searching `string_agg` in the documentation doesn’t take you there.

Comment: Is it possible to keep the resulted output as it is without sorting them?

Answer (score 198):

For Microsoft SQL: Use "WITHIN GROUP"

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

```
SELECT
  STRING_AGG(prod, '|') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY product)
FROM ...
```

Comment: The question was about PostgreSQL. The `WITHIN GROUP` clause does not apply to the `string_agg` function, as it does with Microsoft SQL.

Comment: The question was about string_agg.  Postgres was incidental to his question and he mentioned it last.  The question is useful to others as well.

Comment: If this syntax gives you syntax errors, check your compatibility level: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43611024/issue-with-string-agg-within-group-and-visual-studio

Answer (score 4):

This seems to sort numerically even with casting:

```sql
select string_agg(cast (o.id as varchar),',' order by o.id) from tb_organisation o 
    inner join tb_country c on o.country_fk = c.id 
        where c.name ilike '%united%' group by c.id;
```

Comment: Hi, you order by o.id not the casted value, should look like:   
```select string_agg(cast (o.id as varchar),',' order by cast (o.id as varchar))```

Answer (score 2):

```
select string_agg(prod,' | ') FROM 
  (SELECT product as prod FROM tblproducts ORDER BY product )MAIN;
```

[**SQL FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9c588/8)

Comment: I had the same problem as OP, and this approach was my first thought, but unfortunately it doesn't work (which brought me here), whereas Igor's does.

Comment: On my side, both approaches (Ilesh's and Igor's) worked.

Comment: Wrong answer. It might work but is not guaranteed to work.

Comment: Relational Database is based in part on mathematical sets, and this is reflected in the fact that a basic principle in SQL is that row order is not significant. Even if you were to include an `ORDER BY` clause in the sub query, the `FROM` clause doesn’t necessarily get the data in order. If this works, it is pure luck.

Comment: I was happily using this solution for a long time, until one day some data entered my system that caused this to no longer work. It's very deceptive.  (though to Ilesh's defence the docs do say it will "usually" work:   "Alternatively, supplying the input values from a sorted subquery will usually work")