# PostgreSQL: How to concatenate rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

So, I have a pretty unconventional problem. I would like to be able to concatenate rows with the same ID into one big row. To illustrate my problem let me provide an example. Here is the query:

```
SELECT b.id AS "ID",
       m.content AS "Conversation"
FROM bookings b 
INNER JOIN conversations c on b.id = c.conversable_id AND c.conversable_type = 'Booking'
INNER JOIN messages m on m.conversation_id = c.id
WHERE b.state IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY 1,2
LIMIT 1000;
```

And here is the output:

```
ID     **Conversation
1223    "blah, blah, blah, blah"
1223    " ... blaaaah, blah.."
1223    "more blaaah"
1223    "last blah"
5000    "new id, with more blah"
5000    "and the blah continues"
```

Is there a way to concatenate the conversation rows into one aggregate row while keeping the ID?

Like this:

```
ID     Conversation
1223    "blah, blah, blah, blah, ... blaaaah blah.. more blaaah, last blah"
5000    "new id, with more blah and the blah continues"
```

I am sure there is an efficient way to do this. I just can't figure it out on my own.

Comment: `group_concat()` is your friend.

Comment: Could be. Maybe `string_agg()` , then?

Comment: Quick question though. How can I make a line break for each new message?

Comment: There are no linebreaks. You could use `string_agg( colx, e'\n' )` , but it will still be part of the output record.field.

Answer (score 6):

I was able to solve my own problem by looking at the brilliant answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24906826/how-to-get-result-from-string-agg-with-a-proper-order-by). It was as simple as using the PostgreSQL `string_agg()`-function.